# Preventing WPF CommandManager executing CanExecute

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to prevent the WPF CommandManager from executing it's attached CanExecute delegates?

I have an Unhandled Exception Handler routine that displays an error window for the user.  I have a situation at the moment where an exception is being thrown as part of a CanExecute chain.  This invokes the exception handler, which displays the window.  At this point, CommandManager kicks in and requeries the CanExecute, throwing another exception, invoking the handler, showing another window, requerying CanExecute, throwing another exception... etc. etc. etc.

I somehow need to prevent this rerunning of CanExecute.  I have tried to simply ignore subsequent errors in the handler, but this means that the exception information in the error window is blank.

Comment: Have you had to manually link your commands `CanExecuteChanged` event to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event?

Comment: I'm using the Cinch framework, which includes a SimpleCommand class that does this as per Josh Smith's implementation here: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/allowing-commandmanager-to-query-your-icommand-objects/

Comment: consider using a different command implementation. if you're interested, try PerrypheralFramework.WPF. this means using the Framework's ViewModelBase for it to work. the commands are Queried when a property is changed or when you ask a view model to raise the event for all commands within it using one view model method.

Answer (score 0):

The best resource is the to look off is from the [ICommand Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) which has the [CanExecuteChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Operations which subscribe to that event will be notified to disable itself.

It is unclear what your structure is setup as, but I would surmise that the originating operation could fire this event upon starting the process, then when it is done fire the event again to announce that other command processed can run.

**Example** of the originating command operation to notify others to inspect status before turning on their commands:

```
private void DoTheCommand()
{
    _isProcessingCabExecute = false;       // Turn off all related for this 
                                           // command (is Execute).

    _opCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();   // Inform all subscribed to check status 
                                           // and disable where possible.

    // The operation

    _isProcessingCabExecute = true;        // All done turn it back on
    _opCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); // Resume operations.
}
```